# Java. IO. Как из байтов собрать файл?

Tags: java, io

У меня через сокет приходит поток байтов которые мне надо собрать в файл. Но как это сделать c файлом? С строкой понятно можно просто написать

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream(); 
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);
String s = in.readUTF()
```

А как с файлом аналогичную ситуацию создать?

можно читать просто `in.read()` и он мне вернет `int`. Как я из него объект `File` обратно могу собрать?

Могу ли я отправить файл в сокет так?:

```
void upload(String path) {
        try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream()) {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
            int i = in.read();
            while (i != -1) {
                подскажите что тут?
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
// Саздаём пустой массив байтов из 
byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
// Читаем из InputStream
initialStream.read(buffer);
// Саздаём файл  ...
File file = new File("path to your file..");
// Саздаём OutputStream из файла  ...
OutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
// Записываем массив байтов в файл
outStream.write(buffer);
```

Comment: initialStream.read(buffer); это вы имели в виду input.read(buffer)? просто input.read(buffer) возвращает int а что с ним он не нужен?

Comment: Да там должно было

Comment: Да там должно было input.read(buffer). .read метод возврашшает buffer.length  из Инпутстрима в массив buffer

Comment: А возврашшет он общее количество прочитанных байтов в буфер, или -1, если нет больше данных, тоест конец потока был достигнут.

Comment: Спасибо. Я понял это просто флаг чтоб понять где конец. А как отправить в сокет?

Comment: Здес вы просто отправляете в сокет количество прочитанных байтов. 
Нужно делат так:
void upload(String path) {
        try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream()) {

            File file = new File(path);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            bufferedInputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

Comment: А BufferedInputStream не надо через трай-ресурсы закрывать?

Comment: Да надо.Можно исползовать "Java Automatic Resource Management" . Немного корректируем код :
<p>
void upload(String path) {
        try (OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
             BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(path)))) {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferedInputStream.available()];
            bufferedInputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
</p>

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте код приведенный ниже (не забудьте, про кодировку)

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(input);

try (OutputStream outputStream = Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int count = 0;
   while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1)
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```